# Upgrade Magento2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Currently i have a Magento ver 2.2.8 now I want to upgrade my Magento version to Magento ver. 2.3.2 so I want to know about what will be the best approach to achieve this smoothly.

Comment: i have enterprise version

Answer (score 2):

> Command Line Upgrade is always Preferable:
>
> **Step 1:** Backup the existing composer.json file in the Magento installation directory.
>
> **Step 2:** Remove any unnecessary packages before upgrading to Magento 2.3.2.
>
> ```
> composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
> ```
>
> **Step 3:** Then you need to deactivate the Magento Open Source update.
>
> ```
> composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
> ```
>
> **Step 4:** Indicate to Magento 2.3.2
>
> ```
> composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
> ```
>
> **Step 5:** Open composer.json and edit the “autoload”
>
> ```
> "autoload": {
> "psr-4": {
> "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
> "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
> "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
> "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
> },
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> **Step 6:** Modify the Magento updater
>
> You need to modify the Magento updater if it is installed (which
>   located in /update). First, you need to backup
>   and remove the old updater. Then, create a Composer project.
>
> ```
> composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 temp_dir --no-install
> ```
>
> **Step 7:** Check metadata in “name“, “version“, and “description” fields in the /composer.json file. If everything
>   is okay, apply update.
>
> ```
> composer update
> ```
>
> **Step 8:** Clear caches and generated content
>
> ```
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/cache/*
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/var/page_cache/*
> rm -rf <Magento install dir>/generated/code/*
> ```
>
> **Step 9:** Update the database schema and data
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> ```
>
> **Step 10:** Disable maintenance mode
>
> ```
> php bin/magento maintenance:disable
> ```
>
> **Step 11:** Restart Varnish
>
> ```
> service varnish restart
> ```
>
> **Hope this will help You!!**

Comment: For Enterprise Version

Comment: I would do this in a separate git branch, tar.gz ./vendor directory and dump database for safe measure in case you ever want to revert back.

Answer (score 2):

> You can upgrade your Magento application from the command line

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
```

**Specify additional packages**

```
composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.13.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~1.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.14 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 --sort-packages --no-update
```

**Remove unused packages**

```
composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
```

**Update autoload**

Open `composer.json` and edit the "autoload": "psr-4" section to include "Zend\Mvc\Controller\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/":

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    //...
}
```

**Remove the old update/ directory and move temp_dir/update/ to the update/ directory:**

```
rm -rf update

mv temp_dir/update .

rm -rf temp_dir
```

**Apply updates**

```
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf var/generation/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

For more details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2 --no-update . This command only different from community edition